# What is the best way of MongoDB Query Reporting in C#?

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I'm converting my Reporting website from MySQL to MongoDB in C#.
So far, I'm happy with MongoDB Inserting Data.
Now, from collection, I need to print out as .

Original, my query is like this

```
strSQL = "SELECT " +
                " '" + strSearchingStartDate + "' AS SearchStartDate, '" + strSearchingEndDate + "' AS SearchEndDate, '" + strCurrentUserName + "' as WhoPrint, " +
                " machinelograwdata.MachineID , " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter1 AS 'Code', " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter42 AS 'Orders', " +
                " Temp2.HideStartTime AS StartTime, " +
                " machinelograwdata.EndTime, " +
                " UNIX_TIMESTAMP(machinelograwdata.EndTime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Temp2.HideStartTime) AS Duration, " +
                " Temp.StartTime AS CutStartTime, " +
                " Temp.EndTime AS CutEndTime, " +
                " Temp.Duration AS CutDuration, " +
                " NULL AS NestingStartTime, " +
                " NULL AS NestingEndTime, " +
                " '0.00' AS NestingDuration, " +
                " '0.00' AS 'SupplierAream2', " +
                " ROUND(machinelograwdata.Parameter3 / 1000000, 2) AS 'GrossAream2', " +
                " ROUND(machinelograwdata.Parameter26 / 1000000, 2) AS 'NetAream2', " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter27 AS 'YieldPercen', " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter25 AS 'NoPiece', " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter24 AS 'Material', " +
                " machinelograwdata.Parameter44 AS 'Models', " +
                " ROUND(machinelograwdata.Parameter9 / 1000000, 2) AS 'Quantity0Area', " +
                " '0.00' AS 'Quantity1Area', " +
                " '0.00' AS 'Quantity2Area' " +
                " FROM " +
                " machinelograwdata " +
                " INNER JOIN catalogue" +
                " ON machinelograwdata.EventID = catalogue.CatalogueID " +
                " LEFT JOIN " +
                "   (SELECT MachineID, Parameter1, EndTime, StartTime,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(EndTime) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(StartTime) AS Duration " +
                "   FROM " +
                "     (SELECT machinelograwdata.MachineID, machinelograwdata.Parameter1, " +
                "         MAX(machinelograwdata.EndTime) AS EndTime, " +
                "         MIN(machinelograwdata.StartTime) AS StartTime " +
                "   FROM " +
                "     machinelograwdata, catalogue " +
                "   WHERE " +
                "     machinelograwdata.EventID = catalogue.CatalogueID " +
                "         AND catalogue.CatalogueGroup = 'EventDesc' " +
                "         AND StartTime >= '" + strSearchingStartDate + "' " +
                "         AND StartTime <= '" + strSearchingEndDate + "' " +
                "         AND EventID = '15' " +
                "         AND machinelograwdata.Parameter2 = '0' " +
                "   GROUP BY machinelograwdata.Parameter1, machinelograwdata.MachineID) M) Temp  " +
                " ON Temp.Parameter1 = machinelograwdata.Parameter1 " +
                "    AND Temp.MachineID = machinelograwdata.MachineID " +
                " LEFT JOIN " +
                "   (SELECT MachineID, Parameter1, MIN(StartTime)AS HideStartTime " +
                "   FROM machinelograwdata " +
                "   WHERE EventID = '13' " +
                "     AND machinelograwdata.StartTime <= '" + strSearchingEndDate + "' " +
                "     AND machinelograwdata.StartTime >= '" + strSearchingStartDate + "' " +
                "   GROUP BY MachineID, Parameter1) Temp2 " +
                " ON Temp2.Parameter1 = machinelograwdata.Parameter1 " +
                "    AND Temp2.MachineID = machinelograwdata.MachineID " +
                " WHERE catalogue.CatalogueGroup = 'EventDesc' " +
                "     AND machinelograwdata.StartTime <= '" + strSearchingEndDate + "' " +
                "     AND machinelograwdata.StartTime >= '" + strSearchingStartDate + "' " +
                "     AND EventID = '14' " +
                "     AND CONVERT(Parameter35, DECIMAL) <> 0 " +
                " ORDER BY machinelograwdata.MachineID , machinelograwdata.StartTime;  ";
```

my question is, is it possible for me to write the same query with MongoDB ?

and is there "View" concept on MongoDB? because I have another MySQL Report query using View.

I appreciate if you can have any suggestion or advice.
Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB and MySQL are two very different database solutions. Both follow different approach in terms of maintaining data. MongoDB is NO SQL database means data stored in it is not bound with schema like data in MySQL databases.

You cannot able fetch data from MongoDB using SQL query. MongoDB has its own query engine (powered by Javascript) to fetch data.

Concept of view is not supported in MongoDB.

As you able to load data in MongoDB from MySQL using C#, I would recommend to check [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) official [C# drivers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/) for map reduce operations.

One approach would be to fetch data in memory and then build report. You might also find some online solutions to map SQL query to Mongo like [this](http://www.querymongo.com/)

Comment: Hi @Monk-Who-Code,
Thank you for your suggestion.
Look like, I will have to do homework to work on Reporting with MongoDB.

I think, I load MongoDB in Memory and handle it.
so, the performance is what I should take care.